# How to edit keybindings in PyDev?

Tags: python, pydev, key-bindings

It is said [here](http://pydev.org/manual_adv_keybindings.html) that if you type Ctrl+Shift+L twice, it will bring you to the place where you can edit/see the keybindings you have in your installation.But it just doesn't work in my PyDev,nothing happens after typing Ctrl+Shift+L

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it doesn't work, go to General > Keys in Preferences.